# How do I handle messages sent to actors being passivated

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I have to create a set of persistent actors and route messages to them by some id.
When I do this, in my router actor I look up the target one using something like:

```
context.child(id) getOrElse create(id) - creating actors by context.actorOf()
```

and after the router has found the child, it forwards the message (otherwise creates the child first).

To save the space, I'm also using some sort of custom passivation for the child actors by calling on them - `setReceiveTimeout` => `ReceiveTimeout` => send the actor to be passivated a custom Shutdown message, on receiving which it calls `context.stop(self)`.

What if the actual actor shutdown occurs just after the parent actor has obtained the `ActorRef` to the child which is already in progress of stopping, but before it forwards the message? Would the message be lost?

I thought this problem is handled in akka sharding (by ShardRegion, probably) by saving the incoming messages and replaying them on actor reactivation.

The problem is due to requirements I cannot use Akka Sharding.
Is there a ready solution or a pattern to the problem of handling messages for passivating actors?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The router and the child actor are running async, so there's always a chance that when the child call `context.stop(self)` there are still messages pending in mailbox.  In that case, those messages will be lost (routed to deadletter)

To avoid message lost, child cannot shutdown on it's own and need to coordinate with the router.  E.g.:

1. child: `setReceiveTimeout`
2. child: on receiving `ReceiveTimeout`, send a custom `Stopping` message to router
3. router: on receiving `Stopping`, stop routing message to child and send custom `Stop` message (or `PoisonPill`) to child
4. child: on receiving `Stop`, call `context.stop(self)`

In step 3, router might need to maintain it's own map of children instead of relying on `context.child`

And in step 4, since the order of messages between two actors are guaranteed, the `Stop` message will always be the last from router thus safe to stop.

Comment: So do I also need to stash/save to a map the message which cannot be delivered, and then unstash it ? Since the passivated actor needs to be activated on the first incoming message anyway.

Comment: As to sending the PoisonPill - not sure it works well with persistent actors (as in my case)